# How to send a Bitcoin transaction only using the seed phrase using NodeJS?

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, seed, javascript, nodejs

I am working on a NodeJS script that allows you to enter your 12-words-long Bitcoin secret recovery phrase and automatically withdraw all of your coins to a defined wallet address.

The script is for people like me (with a hundred paper wallets) to withdraw their funds quickly to one wallet without restoring every wallet by hand.

How can I do this? I did some research myself, but it seems impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with [bcoin](https://bcoin.io), a NodeJS bitcoin library that supports mnemonics, private keys, tx construction, etc... but you will still need a full node (or blockexplorer API) to get the UTXO you can spend with your key. Also, keep in mind handling seed phrases or typing seed phrases into *anything* is fraught with risk and you should be very careful the tools you choose to do this.

Anyway, I have an applet called [brainsweeper](https://starservice.space/brainsweeper/) (source code [here](https://github.com/pinheadmz/brainsweeper)) that does the second part of your question, using bcoin: it uses the blockstream.info API to get UTXO associated with an address, constructs a transaction that sweeps all the UTXO to a new address, signs it and the uses the blockstream.info API again to broadcast the completed TX.

If you need help using bcoin there is a discussion channel on [telegram](https://t.me/bcoinorg)